# Multideminsional array sorting and adding a key to an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm building a student result system now i want to sort the students according to their average scores, I have an array like this

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [student] => STD-000001
        [marks] => 78
        [total_subjects] => 1
        [avarage] => 78
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [student] => STD-000002
        [marks] => 60.4
        [total_subjects] => 1
        [avarage] => 60.4
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [student] => STD-000013
        [marks] => 0
        [total_subjects] => 0
        [avarage] => 0
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [student] => STD-000014
        [marks] => 0
        [total_subjects] => 0
        [avarage] => 0
    )
)
```

now I want to sort the array by `avarage` key then create a new array by adding a new key `position`. I expect an array like this

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [student] => STD-000001
        [marks] => 78
        [total_subjects] => 1
        [avarage] => 78
        [position] => 1 )
    [1] => Array (
        [student] => STD-000002
        [marks] => 60.4
        [total_subjects] => 1
        [avarage] => 60.4
        [position] => 2
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [student] => STD-000013
        [marks] => 0
        [total_subjects] => 0
        [avarage] => 0
        [position] => 3
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [student] => STD-000014
        [marks] => 0
        [total_subjects] => 0
        [avarage] => 0
        [position] => 3
    )
)
```

As you can see the greater `average` the earlier the `position`, and if the `average` matches it should have the same `position` value.
i have tried methods like

```
$class_students is the array above
   $sort_col = [];
        foreach ($class_students as $key => $row) {
            $sort_col[$key] = $row['avarage'];
        }
        array_multisort($sort_col, SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $class_students);
```

This works by sorting the 'average' but i cant find a way to add a new key 'position' in array.

Answer (score 1):

First use `usort`, like so:

```
usort($class_students, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['avarage'] < $b['avarage'];
});
```

Lastly, use following to add position:

```
$pos = 1;
foreach ($class_students as $key => $value) {
    if ($key > 0 && $value['avarage'] < $class_students[$key - 1]['avarage']) {
        $pos += 1;
    }
    $class_students[$key]['position'] = $pos;
}
```

I shuffled the original array, and tested above code, here is the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [student] => STD-000001
            [marks] => 78
            [total_subjects] => 1
            [avarage] => 78
            [position] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [student] => STD-000002
            [marks] => 60.4
            [total_subjects] => 1
            [avarage] => 60.4
            [position] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [student] => STD-000014
            [marks] => 0
            [total_subjects] => 0
            [avarage] => 0
            [position] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [student] => STD-000013
            [marks] => 0
            [total_subjects] => 0
            [avarage] => 0
            [position] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: From the post: "As you can see the greater average the earlier the position, and if the average matches it should have the same position value."

Comment: Missed that part, fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can sort using `array_column($class_students, 'avarage')` which will remove your foreach loop. The you can traverse array and add new key-value in it by comparing avg.

```
array_multisort(array_column($class_students, 'avarage'), SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $class_students);
$last_avg = "";
$pos = 0;
foreach ($class_students as $key => &$value) {
  $avg = $value['avarage'];
  if($last_avg != $avg)
    $pos++;
  $value['position']=$pos;
  $last_avg = $avg;   

}
```

Answer (score -1):

[usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) is the function you should use.

```
function compare($a, $b)
{
    return $b->average - $a->average;
}

usort($students, "compare");
```

As for the position - you don't need a position property.

Just use the index after sorting the array.

```
foreach ($students as $key => $value) {
    $position = $key+1;
    //if you really insist on having that property:
    $students[$key]['position'] = $key+1;
}
```

Comment: @Syscall technically any integer, so I think a difference is suitable here, too. Fixed this.

Comment: how do you add the new key `position`?

Comment: @codekaizer you can loop over all the elements and update the position based on the current $i.

Comment: Or just use the current index in that array instead of having a separate position property.

Comment: the purpose of the position is to check if previous student has the same average or not.

Answer (score -1):

You can use array_column to get all the values and sort them.
Then use the new array keys in a loop to build your result array and add position.

```
$avarage = array_column($arr, "avarage");

Arsort($avarage); //sort on values.
$i=0;
Foreach($avarage as $key => $val){
    $res[$i] = $arr[$key];
    $res[$i]['position'] = $i+1;
    $i++;
}
Var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/8XUED

Comment: from the post: "As you can see the greater average the earlier the position, and if the average matches it should have the same position value."